# Go to a nested ViewController from a main TabBarController programmatically in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, tabbarcontroller

I have the following ViewController structure, see image below.

Whenever I want to move from `ViewController 1` to any of the other main controllers I use `self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = indexNumber`

```
// for instance, this would take me to ViewController 3
self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 2
```

Based on the picture below, how can I go from `ViewController 1` to `TargetViewController` programmatically when a button is tapped in ViewController 1?

FYI -
In the picture below I'm showing a button in `ViewController 3` this is just to show the storyboard structure, the actual button-tap will happen in `ViewController 1`

[image]

### EDIT:

Here is how you do it based on `Prashant Tukadiya`'s answer.

### ViewController 1

In `ViewController 1` add the following in your tap event.

```
    self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 2
    let nav = (self.tabBarController?.viewControllers?[2] as? UINavigationController)
    let vc =  TargetViewController.viewController()
    nav?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

### TargetViewController

1. In your `TargetViewController` add the following class method.

   class func viewController() ->  TargetViewController {
       let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
       return storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "targetViewControllerID") as! TargetViewController
   }
2. Add `targetViewControllerID` in the Storyboard ID field.

Comment: is it Viewcontroller-1 to ViewController-3 to TargetViewController as per your diagram?

Comment: From `ViewController 1` straight to `TargetViewController`. The button tap would happen in `ViewController 1`.

Comment: The back button on TargetViewController should take you to VC1 or VC3?

Comment: I want to go from `ViewController 1`  to `TargetViewController` programmatically.

Comment: Yes, but if you want to go back from the TargetViewController (<Back navigation bar button), should you stay in the first tab hierarchy or you should be in the hierarchy of tab 3?

Comment: Oh, it needs to go back to its parent `ViewController 3`. I was assuming that it would happen automatically.

Comment: Hey, @fs_tigre please check my answer may be it will help you.

Comment: If that's the case, @Sumitsingh is the way to go :).
1. Select 3rd tab.
2. Get nav controller for 3rd tab.
3. Create TargetVC.
4. Push to nav controller for 3rd tab.

Edit: You might need to call popToRoot on the navigation controller to avoid messes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly give identifier  to the TargetViewController from storyboard and load from storyboard  then and push or present it.

like add this method in your `TargetViewController`

```
class func viewController () ->  TargetViewController {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    return storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "yourIdentifer") as! TargetViewController
}
```

and on tap event

```
     let vc =  TargetViewController.viewController()

    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

**EDIT**

After reading comments got clear idea about your requirements

On button action from `ViewController1`,  You want to goto `TargetViewController`  but when press back you want back to viewController 3

Select particular index first

```
   self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 2
```

After that you need to grab `UINavigationController`

```
let nav = (self.tabBarController?.viewControllers?[2] as? UINavigationController)
```

then  Push ViewController

```
    let vc =  TargetViewController.viewController()

    nav?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

Note: Don't forgot add identifier to storyboard to `TargetViewController` and also add `class func viewController () ->  TargetViewController` method to TargetViewController

Hope it is helpful

Comment: I couldn't make this work, no error it just doesn't do anything. Thanks.

Comment: @fs_tigre I have tried to edit my answer please verify it is helpful to you or not. let me know if you stuck anywhere

Comment: It worked thanks a lot. Quick question, is there a way to accomplish the same thing but without having the class method in the `TargetViewController`? In other words, I would like to have all the code in the calling method.

Comment: @fs_tigre See this is the way How I use.  I didn't get your point all the code in calling method

Comment: Well I was wondering if the code in the class method could be somehow be incorporated in the tap event.

Comment: @fs_tigre yes it is possible just write `let vc = self.storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "yourIdentifer") as! TargetViewController` instead of     `let vc =  TargetViewController.viewController()`

Comment: Cool, thanks a lot. Just out of curiosity, do you prefer having the class method in the TargetViewController? If yes, why?

Comment: @fs_tigre it is used for code re usability . Now suppose you have to call This vc from 5 different places then you have to write same code at 5 different places. And other example is you change the storyboard identifier then you have to change each and every place. Hope it is helpful

Comment: Got it, makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I was facing same before a couple of days and finally, I got a solution maybe this will help you.

```
    TabController.shared.tabcontroller.selectedIndex = 1
    let navigation  = TabController.shared.tabcontroller.selectedViewController?.navigationController

    let SavedAddress = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SavedAddressVC") as! SavedAddressVC
    navigation?.pushViewController(SavedAddress, animated: true)
```

I have used the same solution. and this is the working code for me.

Comment: Sorry but I don't fully understand the first two lines of your code, is this a singleton of `ViewController 1` or `TargetViewController`? I cannot make it work.

Comment: @fs_tigre it is the singleton class of TabbarController Where all four controllers are added, so when I need TabController in any controller so I can use this.

Let me explain you in Details :

1)TabController.shared.tabcontroller.selectedIndex = 1: This line will redirect to you on ViewController3, In your case you have to pass your index.

2) let navigation  = TabController.shared.tabcontroller.selectedViewController?.navigationController : This line will you give you NavigationController object of selected View controller.

And after you only have to only push to TargertVC

Comment: Thanks you for the explanation, I will give it a try and let you know. I like this because it seem to be less code but I still not sure how is method `tabcontroller` implemented.

Answer (score 1):

In action function of a button in ViewController 1 , you can use this :

```
     func presentMethod(storyBoardName: String, storyBoardID: String) {
        let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: storyBoardName, bundle: nil)
        let newViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: storyBoardID)
        self.definesPresentationContext = true
        self.present(newViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

//usage

 presentMethod(storyBoardName: "Main", storyBoardID: "TargetViewController")
```

Comment: This does take me to `TargetViewController`, the issue is that it doesn't show the back button, as @ Denislava Shentova mentioned it.